# Rest API text field limit

Tags: rest

Let's say you have a function that needs to make an API call to another service to send it a message (say a log message). If in the REST API definition you set the field to a length limit of say 400 (let's say the field name is MyMessage), and the function sets that MyMessage field to a very long message that exceeds 400, what will happen? will the endpoint service receive the message automatically truncated to 400? or will it just not go through?

Comment: Depends on how the backend is coded.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much about content-length errors in the HTTP RFC. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.html#page-119
So it depends on the HTTP server implementation if we are talking about HTTP 1.1. Sometimes 5xx, sometimes 4xx, but usually you got an error message I think.

As of HTTP 2, you will certainly got an error, most probably 400 bad request, because it is a malformed request. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.6

> 8.1.2.6.  Malformed Requests and Responses
>
> A malformed request or response is one that is an otherwise valid
> sequence of HTTP/2 frames but is invalid due to the presence of
> extraneous frames, prohibited header fields, the absence of mandatory
> header fields, or the inclusion of uppercase header field names.
>
> A request or response that includes a payload body can include a
> content-length header field.  A request or response is also malformed
> if the value of a content-length header field does not equal the sum
> of the DATA frame payload lengths that form the body.  A response
> that is defined to have no payload, as described in [RFC7230],
> Section 3.3.2, can have a non-zero content-length header field, even
> though no content is included in DATA frames.
>
> Intermediaries that process HTTP requests or responses (i.e., any
> intermediary not acting as a tunnel) MUST NOT forward a malformed
> request or response.  Malformed requests or responses that are
> detected MUST be treated as a stream error (Section 5.4.2) of type
> PROTOCOL_ERROR.
>
> For malformed requests, a server MAY send an HTTP response prior to
> closing or resetting the stream.  Clients MUST NOT accept a malformed
> response.  Note that these requirements are intended to protect
> against several types of common attacks against HTTP; they are
> deliberately strict because being permissive can expose
> implementations to these vulnerabilities.

Though the easiest way would be trying it out instead of reading RFC-s.